# Speech recognition input screen same for all in android

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I have a problem with my android app with speech recognition.My problem is that I want to show the same speech recognition input screen as is shown from the jellybean keyboard. If I invoke the Speech recognition intent from code, it does not keep listening and stops prematurely.
There must be a simple way to do this, but I can't find it.

here is my code

```
package com.bsdcservices.recognitiontest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final String TAG = "RecognitionTest";
private final int SPEECHRECOGNITION_RESULTCODE = 0;
private EditText editText;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
    Button recognize = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recognize);
    recognize.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
}

public OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startSpeechRecognitionActivity();
    }

};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

void startSpeechRecognitionActivity(){
    //      MyApplication.speechRecognitionActive = true;
    //      main.startSpeechRecognizer(TABSPEAK);
    try{
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault().toString());
        startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECHRECOGNITION_RESULTCODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException error) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Speech recognition is not supported by your device" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch( RuntimeException error ) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), error.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try
    {
        if (requestCode == SPEECHRECOGNITION_RESULTCODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                editText.append(text.get(0));
            }
        }
    } catch( RuntimeException error ) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), error.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is there any information, for example in logcat, that seems of interest?

Comment: no there is nothing in logcat